# java get collection of methods

Tags: java, collections

I have some helper classes for testing with the following structure:

```
public class EntitiesForTest {
    public static Entity firstEntity() {
        return new Entity(/*some dummy data*/)
    }

    public static Entity secondEntity() {...}
    ...
    public static Entity nthEntity() {...}

    public static List<Entity> allEntities() {???}
}
```

The purpose of this classes is to have some objects to test the upper layers of my system, like having some JSON data to test a REST service. This technique is not mine but from an online course I'm taking and is pretty cool.

I'd like to know if there is a way to construct a `List<Entity>` based on the static inherited methods of the class and with the **Collection framework**. I can do `Arrays.asList(/*call the methods one by one comma-separated*/)` but there must be a smarter, functional and reusable way of doing this.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why don't you put the Entities into a static collection and index into that? You can technically use Reflection to gather the entities, but it's going be a lot more ugly.

Comment: By *put the Entities into a static collection and index into that* do you mean to declare a `List` as a static member of the class and adding to the collection in every method? I don't call every static method in my tests, so I think it's not viable. Can you post an answer with examples of what you are saying? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm asking why you need the methods in the first place. I detailed that question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Modern" Way

```
public static List<Entity> getEntities() {
    return Arrays.stream(Foo.class.getMethods()).
            filter(method -> method.getReturnType() == Entity.class && 
                             Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())).
            map(method -> {
                try {
                    return (Entity)method.invoke(null);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e); // exceptions in streams... lol
                }
            }).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I wish I knew a way to avoid the cast, but that's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much! Just one thing: What does mean *"lol"*? I've seen it around but I don't quite understand the meaning. By the context i guess it's something like *"I'm sorry for that"* or *"that's the way it is"* (I'm spanish speaker, sorry)

Comment: *lol* is an acronym which is short for *Laugh out Loud*. Here, I added it because I feel that checked exceptions in lambda functions require you to introduce awkward code, which defeats the brevity that you gain by using a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the samele code for invoking specified methods of `EntitiesForTest` class and collect the return objects:

```
public static List<Entity> allEntities() {
    ArrayList<Entity> list = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    Method[] ma = EntitiesForTest.class.getMethods();
    Object[] emptyObject = new Object[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
        if (ma[i].getReturnType().equals(Entity.class) && 
                ma[i].getParameterTypes().length == 0 && 
                Modifier.isStatic(ma[i].getModifiers())) {
            try {
                Entity e = (Entity)(ma[i].invoke(null, emptyObject));
                list.add(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer makes several assumptions:

- You don't need the individual methods (`firstEntity`, `secondEntity`, etc.)
- The entities only hold data and are not expensive to create and keep around
- You don't need to modify them, which means you wouldn't call your methods multiple times.

These might not hold, because we have no definition of `Entity` or how it's used.

All in all, I'm just removing your methods.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class EntitiesForTest {
    private static final List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(
           new Entity(),
           new Entity(),
           new Entity()
    );

    public static Entity allEntities(int n) {
        return entities.get(n);
    }

    public static List<Entity> allEntities() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(entities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a functional way (in java 8 ) ?

```
public class Entities {

    static class Entity{
        private String x;
        Entity( String x){
            this.x = x;
        }
        public String getX(){
            return x;
        }
    }

       public static Entity firstEntity() { 
           return new Entity("first Entity");
        }
       public static Entity secondEntity() {  
           return new Entity("second Entity");
        }
        public static Entity nthEntity() {
            return new Entity("nth Entity");}

        @FunctionalInterface interface  GetEntity{
            public Entity getEntity();
        }

        public static List<GetEntity> allEntities  = 
             Arrays.asList(Entities::firstEntity, 
                           Entities::secondEntity,
                           Entities::nthEntity);

        public static void main(String ...p){
            allEntities
                .stream()
                .forEach(x->{System.out.println(x.getEntity().getX());});
        }
}
```